# Kalman filter MLE parameter estimation

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I am having trouble estimating the parameters of my state space model which I want to use to build my Kalman filter in Matlab:

```
 S_t = S_(t-1)+e_t
 Y_t = B*S_t+v_t
```

Where `Y_t` is the observation matrix containing about 20 time series and `S_t` is supposed to be a scalar. I have not found any example code which estimates my `B` parameter matrix and all my testing has been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Hi. StackOverflow usually rejects answers that show no effort, so please show what you've done so far, and explain why it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain you in simple words what you should do with Kalman Filter. Please ask and provide more information if you want better advice.

In Kalman filter you attempt to estimate the true state of a dynamical system (which changes with time). The state in your case is `S_t` (could be a current from some system, a GPS position, or any other number or set of numbers). In the dynamical system normally you have a transition matrix which tells you about change from state `S_(t-1)` to state `S_t`. As you wrote it seems that your transition matrix will be equal to 1. In other words you should expect the same value as the previous value only with added Gaussian noise. The Gaussian noise come from all different sources which are difficult to model and is uncorrelated with your state.

Now the state of your system is normally measured by some sensor and you have a reading `Y_t` from the sensor. The reading is related to state by `B` observation matrix. Every sensor has its noise `v_t` which comes from imperfection of the sensor. And the `Y_t` is a reading of your state which you want to estimate.

In this what you wrote I can understand you have 20 readings from `Y_1` to `Y_20`. you want to estimate the true value of the state of the dynamical system after 20 reading, let say 20 seconds. First you need to think if you are correct that your transition matrix is A=1 and `S_t=A*S_(t-1)+e_t` is the same as `S_t=S_(t-1)+e_t`. To model `A` you need some knowledge of your dynamical system, very often it is modeled by use of differential equations. After you modeled the system think about relation between this what you want to estimate and your measurement (what comes on your sensor), this leads to your `B`.

The Kalman filter is an iterative filter so for your time series `Y` you plug in your model and iterate over measurement. You should finish with estimation for `Y-2`, `Y_3`, ... up to `Y_20` along with error covariance which tells you how good your estimation is.

Think about this procedure and if you want any help, ask good question with more details provided as suggested in the comments.

Good luck